# Is a different version of python being used when the code is run in visual studio Code?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn more about Python in my spare time. I am a .net developer. I have downloaded a simple private open source project. The developer of the repository advised me to clone the repository and then run the project:

```
source .env/bin/activate
python3.6 ./project/main.py -c config.json
```

It works as expected. I am now thinking about debugging so that I can step through the code and debug it. Therefore I have downloaded Visual Studio Code and then installed the Python extension. I then start debugging and everything still works as expected. I opened the Visual Studio Code terminal and I see that Visual Studio Code runs the following:

```
bert@bertvb:~/myapp$ source /home/bert/myapp/.env/bin/activate
(.env) bert@bertvb:~/myapp$  /usr/bin/env /home/bert/myapp/.env/bin/python /home/bert/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 43369 -- /home/bert/myapp/myapp/main.py -c config.json
```

however, when debugging in visual studio code; there are exceptions being thrown e.g. `'JSONDecodeError' object is not subscriptable` and `File not found error` etc.

Comment: Then you first have to debug the project or you have enabled break on all exceptions

Comment: @rioV8, Thanks.  It was just breaking on all exceptions as you say.  If you would like to post an answer then I will mark it.