# VS Code: command inserted on every terminal open; how to disable

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set up pyenv a while back as an experiment, and I have since removed it out of annoyance. However, every time I open a terminal in VS Code, it inserts the command `pyenv shell 3.10.4`, which is no longer valid. I have looked everywhere in the settings to try to figure out where this is coming from to prevent it, but I cannot figure it out.

Where is this command coming from, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How come VS Code activates the virtualenv automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956384/how-come-vs-code-activates-the-virtualenv-automatically)

Comment: No. I don't mind having it activate the correct environment. The problem was a heisenbug where there was temporarily no visible UI element or setting for changing that environment back to the default.

Comment: well, the title of your post is not about that problem. your title should represent what you question is. a mismatch in what your title represents and what you are actually interested in is a problem. I suggest that you fix it. in fact, the rest of your question doesn't even mention this problem. a question should contain enough information that anyone could answer it with just that info. the fact that you are self-answering with info that only you have is also a problem. that's not a good question.

Comment: @starball exactly how was I supposed to know that a UI element was not there? By definition, I couldn't see it. The fact of the matter is that I wanted to know how to fix the thing, and the UI element that allowed me to fix it did not exist for a while. I'm inclined to think that this question itself is useless since it was a heisenbug. I just posted here out of desperation.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more playing around, the version thingy finally showed up again in the lower right corner of the editor (it was not there previously) next to the language indicator. After clicking on it, I was able to reset it to the global default, and it no longer inserts the errant command into new terminals. Why this interpreter selector disappeared and refused to show up for half an hour is anyone's guess.